# Facebook chat client for mac with block friends option

Tags: osx-lion, chat, facebook

IS there any desktop Facebook chat client for OS X Lion where one can block certain users? This can probably done through the web but I want to block everybody by default and then unblock only selected people. I have many Facebook friends and it is a mess when all of them want to talk with me at the same time

Comment: Since there's about three IM clients for OS X that can handle Facebook, which of these have you tried and why don't they work for you?

Comment: I have tried iChat and works fine, but I can not block users. I read about pidgin but it seems that it can not block users neither

Comment: How about Adium, Trillian?